# How to persist Google Apps HtmlObject created with template.evaluate() to a URL?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using a Google Spreadsheet and its triggered App Script to compose and send daily status information in an html-formatted email.  The email message body is composed using an html template into which token data are inserted from spreadsheet data and calculations.  After insertion, the HtmlObject becomes the body of the email message using code like the following:

```
htmlBody = template.evaluate();
MailApp.sendEmail({
              to: emailRecipients,
              replyTo: emailReply,
              subject: 'Today's Management Report',
              htmlBody: htmlBody.getContent(),
            });
```

I would also like to post the daily HtmlObject (Management Report) on our website but I cannot find a method to persist the object to a URL.  Can anyone provide some guidance how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to create a [google web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). You cannot get a URL from a HtmlObject, it is not a web page. However, since you already have HtmlObject you can host on the web using a google web app.

Answer (score 1):

I will add to Jack Brown's comment above about deploying the HtmlObject as a Web app. Once you have deployed the HTML, you can get the URL with the ScriptApp service. The documentation provides an example close to what I think you are looking for: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service#getUrl()

```
 // Mail the URL of the published web app.
 MailApp.sendMail("myself@example.com", "My Snazzy App",
   "My new app is now available at " + ScriptApp.getService().getUrl());
```

Comment: Thanks to Jordan Rhea and Jack Brown for the suggestions. Not being familiar with deploying the HtmlObject as a Web app, I tried the simpler approach of converting the HtmlOutput to PDF and saving in my root Drive folder with the following code:

Comment: Thanks to @Jordan Rhea and Jack Brown for the suggestions. Not being familiar with deploying the HtmlObject as a Web app, I tried the simpler approach of converting the HtmlOutput to PDF and saving in my root Drive folder.  Now I need to figure out how to move the PDF file into the Public folder where other data assets are stored for our Google website. Any further suggestions in accomplishing this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps others, here is the gs code I used to persist the blob and move it from Drive's root folder to its target destination folder:

```
    // create pdf version of daily report
      var title = "Daily Operations Summary - " + Utilities.formatDate(currStatusDate,'MST','MM/dd/yyyy') + ".pdf";
      var htmlDaily = htmlBody.getContent();
      var blob = Utilities.newBlob(htmlDaily, 'text/html').getAs('application/pdf').setName(title);

    // save file and move to target folder
      var fileID = DriveApp.createFile(blob).getId();
      var destfolderID = "your Google folder GUID";
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
      file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
      DriveApp.getFolderById(destfolderID).addFile(file);
```